When can probabilistic Hamiltonian evolution be represented as a Lindbladian?
Suppose I have a Hamiltonian $H = \sum_i h_i$, where the $h_i$ are the local terms of the Hamiltonian. Now I implement the following quantum channel: $E(\rho) = \sum_j p_j e^{-ih_j}\rho e^{ih_j}$ where the $\{p_j\}_j$ are probabilities and $h_j$ are a set of local Hamiltonian terms. That is, I am probabilistically applying a Hamiltonian evolution. The full evolution of the system is given by repeated applications of this channel, so after time $N$ it has evolved under the operator $E^N(\rho)$.
Can I always write this channel as a Liouvillian or Lindbladian? i.e. $E^N = e^{NL}$ for some Liouvillian/Lindbladian $L$ and (integer) $N$? Or potentially another operator $L$ which is not a Lindbladian?
It feels like there should be some implementation of this in the form of a BCH-type formula or Magnus expansion. However, I am yet to find anything about this.
This answer: Pushing a Hamiltonian part into dissipative part in Lindbladian suggests that, if the channel has hermiticity-preserving and trace annihilating, then the operator has a representation as a Liouvillian. However, I cannot find any information about how to find the Liouvillian representation of the channel.

Differentiate your chanel and see if you can get it into the form $LE(\rho)$? Or equivalently Taylor expand, take the first order term and see if it works

Writing a channel as $e^{Lt}$ with $L$ a Lindbladian is the definition of the channel being (time-independent) Markovian. Not only is that not always possible (arXiv), it's also an NP-hard problem.

@FrederikvomEnde I think references you are giving are about determining whether, given some data, there is a Markovian process that generates it? I think this is a different question from what I am asking here. Here I'm wondering whether, given a specific form of channel, can it be reformulated in terms of a time-independent generator.

This paper might be relevant: https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2023-04-06-972/ However, I think they consider only Gaussian noise, so your question might be more general. (I am not familiar enough with that paper to say more right now.)

-In general, if a quantum channel represents a continuous time Markovian process, it should have a representation as a Lindbladian. To find such a Liouvillian $L$ for the channel $ E $, one approach is to interpret the discrete map $ E(\rho) $ as a small time step of a continuous time evolution,
$$
E = e^{\mathcal{L} \delta t}.
$$
Then, iterate this process for $ N $ steps
$$
E^N \approx e^{N \mathcal{L} \delta t} = e^{t \mathcal{L}}
$$
-The BCH formula applies to unitary dynamics, but the Lindblad equation is for open systems with dissipation. Therefore,  extra steps are needed.
